# iOS - KML - XML Parsing

Tags: ios, xml, kml

I have a KML (XML) with all coordinates (in Polygons) for all countries, that I need to parse and find in which country is my location.
My approach is to start parsing each country alphabetically until I find my location using this [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10109677/detect-if-a-point-is-inside-a-mkpolygon-overlay).

My question here is that I think that my approach is too slow especially if my country is United States which at the end of the KML. Is there anyway to eliminate some countries faster?